# How to replace all values in a column by a specific value in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose this is my initial excel sheet

[image]

I want to replace all the non-empty cells in column C with the string "Title" excluding the column header.

The output should be like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Both image is same. Did you try anything? Show us what you tried already.

Comment: My apology. You can check it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below sub.

```
Sub FillTitle()
Dim lrow As Long
Dim rng As Range

    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 'Detect last data entry row in Column C.
    
    For Each rng In Range("C2:C" & lrow)
        If rng <> "" Then
            rng = "Title"
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Range has Replace method:

```
Sub ReplaceAll()
   With ActiveSheet
        Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1), .Columns("C")).Replace What:="*", Replacement:="Tester"
        
        ' reset Find/Replace pattern to default for further use
        .Cells.Find What:="", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlRows, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For small table, just run a for loop:

```
for row=2 to something_large
if cells(row,col)<>"" then cells(row,col)="title"
next row
```

for large table, your best bet is to record a macro: create a filter on the column, filter to nonblank, select all rows, then paste to them. Once you have the macro, modify for general use.

Comment: I'll take this method into consideration for other processes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can choose not use loop as well by using a simple code line like below which will perform the same action.

`Range("C2:C" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Value = "Title"`